# Apply function execute just on subset of dataframe

Tags: pandas, group-by, apply

I have a question regarding the apply function on groupby. I have a dataset with over than 10k matches(rows) and multiple statistics(columns). Then I have some functions, which calculate me more statistics, for example:

```
def last(team): 
    return team["HOME_ATTACKS"].shift(1)

df["HOME_ATTACKS_LAST_MATCH"] = df.groupby("HOME_TEAM").apply(last).reset_index("HOME_TEAM", drop=True)
```

Every day I will add new rows with new matches and I want to execute all functions on that rows, but since it takes really long time, I just want to execute them on the new rows. Unfortunately this doesnt work.

```
df["HOME_ATTACKS_LAST_MATCH"].iloc[-5:] = df.groupby("HOME_TEAM").apply(last).reset_index("HOME_TEAM", drop=True)
```

Comment: Why don't you keep track of the newly added rows e.g. using some timestamp and process  only these rows?

Comment: andding to @ShubhamSharma , then you could do a `.loc` based off max(timestamp column) and do the groupby apply

Comment: Can you please share a code with example above? Thanks